# Problema ao criar custom components no JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

estou tendo problemas ao criar componentes customizados no JSF, na verdade é a primeira vez.

Achei alguns guias na internet mas não tem dado certo.

O que fiz foi o seguinte.

Criei o `custom.taglib.xml` dentro da pasta `WEB-INF` e seu conteúdo é este.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://paradigma.ecred2/facelets</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>btnHelp</tag-name>
        <source>tags\btn-help.xhtml</source>    
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Dentro da pasta `resources`, criei o arquivo `btn-help.xhtml` com o seguinte conteúdo.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="hint" />
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <p>#{cc.attrs.hint}</p>
    </cc:implementation>

</html>
```

E por fim dentro da página onde quero usar este componente, segue o cabeçalho.

```
<ui:composition template="/template/common/pagelayout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ez="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags"
    xmlns:ecred="http://paradigma.ecred2/facelets/tags">
```

E a chamada do componente

```
<ecred:btnHelp hint="Teste"/>
```

O problema é que o componente não esta sendo renderizado, e não sei o que pode estar ocorrendo. A ideia é fazer componentes que sejam mais simples por exemplo.

Fazer um botão de help que já carrega determinada imagem e o desenvolvedor só passe o texto.

```
<p:graphicImage url="#{resource['images:help-icon.png']}" title="#{cc.attrs.hint}"/>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Componentes customizados

Fiz uma implementação há algum tempo e consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

1. Coloquei meus componentes no diretório `src/main/webapp/resources/component-base/`. Note que o projeto segue a estrutura de diretórios do Maven, então adapte à sua estrutura se necessário.
2. Importei os componentes daquele diretório através da declaração `xmlns:mycomp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/component-base"`

Pronto! Agora é só usar as tags, sendo os nomes delas iguais aos nomes dos seus respectivos arquivos `.xhtml`.

A URL `http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/` é especial e diz ao JSF para procurar os arquivos naquele diretório.

## Funções customizadas

Nesse mesmo projeto criei também algumas funções utilitárias.

Primeiro criei o arquivo `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/commons.taglib.xml` com o conteúdo mais ou menos assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://empresa.com.br/functions</namespace>

    <function>
        <function-name>acesso</function-name>
        <function-class>br.com.empresa.commons.Functions</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean acesso(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>acessoItem</function-name>
        <function-class>br.com.empresa.commons.Functions</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean acessoItem(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Implementei a classe de funções com os métodos estáticos, conforme o exemplo a seguir:

```
package br.com.empresa.commons;

/**
 * Funções de taglib JSF para verificar a permissão individual de componentes das telas.
 */
public final class Functions {

    public static boolean acesso(String nome) {
        ...
    }

    public static boolean acessoItem(String prefixoSistema, String nome, String item) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Depois importei as funções com a declaração `xmlns:fn="http://empresa.com.br/functions" e usei em expressões EL assim:

```xml
<p:commandButton
                 id="botaoEditar"
                 styleClass="botao-editar"
                 icon="icon-edit" 
                 ajax="false"
                 immediate="true"
                 disabled="#{not fn:acessoItem('privilegio-alterar')}">
```

Comment: Grande @utluiz, tudo bem? Cara eu fiz aqui e agora reconheceu quando usei aquela declaração de `namespace`, mas não tem como colocar uma como eu quero? E quando vc utiliza o `ctrl` + `space` ele mostra o atributos da `tag`?

Comment: @Macario1983 Quando eu fiz a implementação, a declaração de namespace simplesmente não funcionou. Este é um dos motivos pelos quais eu desanimei completamente do JSF. Quando ao *auto-completar*, no meu Eclipse funciona muito bem.

Comment: eu tenho um `ebook` de `JSF`, e tenho que ler, mas na seção de gerar `JAR`, ele usa o `namespace` próprio, talvez para isso que se use. Quanto ao `auto-completar`, me parece que o problema varia de acordo com o `namespace` do `JSF`, usando que vc sugere na sua resposta funciona, mas usando os novos do `JSF 2.2` não deu!